# Resource exhausted Error: Keras using Tensorflow backend

Tags: memory, tensorflow, keras

I created a docker image with Tensorflow and Keras and when I create a container it works fine but only for the first time. The second time when I try to run the same code it gives me an error:

```
2017-10-04 13:57:25.359384: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:660] Bin for 1.12MiB was 1.00MiB, Chunk State:
2017-10-04 13:57:25.359402: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x1041ac00000 of size 1280
2017-10-04 13:57:25.359420: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x1041ac00500 of size 256
2017-10-04 13:57:25.359435: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x1041ac00600 of size 256
2017-10-04 13:57:25.359463: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x1041ac00700 of size 256
2017-10-04 13:57:25.359478: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x1041ac00800 of size 256
2017-10-04 13:57:25.359492: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x1041ac00900 of size 512
2017-10-04 13:57:25.359507: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x1041ac00b00 of size 256
2017-10-04 13:57:25.359521: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x1041ac00c00 of size 256
2017-10-04 13:57:25.359538: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x1041ac00d00 of size 1024
2017-10-04 13:57:25.359551: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x1041ac01100 of size 256
2017-10-04 13:57:25.359565: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x1041ac01200 of size 256
2017-10-04 13:57:25.359581: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x1041ac01300 of size 2048
2017-10-04 13:57:25.359595: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x1041ac01b00 of size 256
2017-10-04 13:57:25.359608: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x1041ac01c00 of size 256
2017-10-04 13:57:25.359624: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x1041ac01d00 of size 256
2017-10-04 13:57:25.359638: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x1041ac01e00 of size 256
2017-10-04 13:57:25.359653: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x1041ac01f00 of size 256
2017-10-04 13:57:25.359666: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x1041ac02000 of size 256
2017-10-04 13:57:25.359679: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x1041ac02100 of size 256
2017-10-04 13:57:25.359695: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x1041ac02200 of size 256
2017-10-04 13:57:25.359708: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x1041ac02300 of size 256
2017-10-04 13:57:25.359722: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x1041ac03f00 of size 256
2017-10-04 13:57:25.359736: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x1041ac28000 of size 256
2017-10-04 13:57:25.359749: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x1041ac70100 of size 512
2017-10-04 13:57:25.359765: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x1041ad00300 of size 512
2017-10-04 13:57:25.359780: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x1041ad00500 of size 1179648
2017-10-04 13:57:25.359793: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x1041ae20500 of size 1024
2017-10-04 13:57:25.359807: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x1041ae20900 of size 3405568
2017-10-04 13:57:25.359821: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:687] Free at 0x1041ac02400 of size 6912
2017-10-04 13:57:25.359835: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:687] Free at 0x1041ac04000 of size 147456
2017-10-04 13:57:25.359849: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:687] Free at 0x1041ac28100 of size 294912
2017-10-04 13:57:25.359863: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:687] Free at 0x1041ac70300 of size 589824
2017-10-04 13:57:25.359878: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:693]      Summary of in-use Chunks by size:
2017-10-04 13:57:25.359896: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:696] 19 Chunks of size 256 totalling 4.8KiB
2017-10-04 13:57:25.359913: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:696] 3 Chunks of size 512 totalling 1.5KiB
2017-10-04 13:57:25.359929: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:696] 2 Chunks of size 1024 totalling 2.0KiB
2017-10-04 13:57:25.359944: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:696] 1 Chunks of size 1280 totalling 1.2KiB
2017-10-04 13:57:25.359960: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:696] 1 Chunks of size 2048 totalling 2.0KiB
2017-10-04 13:57:25.359976: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:696] 1 Chunks of size 1179648 totalling 1.12MiB
2017-10-04 13:57:25.359992: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:696] 1 Chunks of size 3405568 totalling 3.25MiB
2017-10-04 13:57:25.360007: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:700] Sum Total of in-use chunks: 4.38MiB
2017-10-04 13:57:25.360028: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:702] Stats:
Limit:                     5636096
InUse:                     4596992
MaxInUse:                  5636096
NumAllocs:                      32
MaxAllocSize:              3405568

2017-10-04 13:57:25.360052: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:277] *_*_____*_________****************************************************************xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2017-10-04 13:57:25.360084: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[3,3,128,256]
```

I think it has to do with the session and memory leaked but I have no idea how to solve it. Every time I have to delete the container and create a new one just to run one file.

Code:

```
import numpy
from keras.models import Model, load_model
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.layers import Flatten, Dense, Input, concatenate
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, CSVLogger
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

'''
Model Parameters
'''
# dimensions of our images.
model_name = 'Fuse_Net'
img_width, img_height = 224, 224 # Resolution of inputs
channel = 3
nb_train_samples = 29799
nb_validation_samples = 4428
epochs = 20
batch_size = 40

# Dataset for Stream 1
train_data_dir_1 = '2_Dataset/frontalization/training/'
validation_data_dir_1 = '2_Dataset/frontalization/validation/'
# Dataset for Stream 2
train_data_dir_2 = '2_Dataset/patches/training/'
validation_data_dir_2 = '2_Dataset/patches/validation/'

# Custom parameters
nb_class = 12
hidden_dim = 512

'''
Load the models
'''
vgg_model_frontalization = load_model('weights/Stream_1_Frontalization.hdf5')
vgg_model_patch = load_model('weights/Stream_2_Patches.hdf5')

'''
Customize the model
'''
stream_1 = vgg_model_frontalization.get_layer('pool5').output
stream_1 = Flatten(name='flatten-1')(stream_1)

for layer in vgg_model_frontalization.layers:
   layer.name = layer.name + "-model_frontalization"

stream_2 = vgg_model_patch.get_layer('pool5').output
stream_2 = Flatten(name='flatten-2')(stream_2)

for layer in vgg_model_frontalization.layers:
   layer.name = layer.name + "-model_patches"

# fuse_layer = stream_1 + stream_2
fuse_layer = concatenate([stream_1, stream_2])

fuse_layer = Dense(hidden_dim, activation='relu', name='fc6')(fuse_layer)
fuse_layer = Dense(hidden_dim, activation='relu', name='fc7')(fuse_layer)
fuse_layer = Dense(hidden_dim, activation='relu', name='fc8')(fuse_layer)
out = Dense(nb_class, activation='softmax', name='fc9')(fuse_layer)

custom_vgg_model = Model(
    [vgg_model_frontalization.input, vgg_model_patch.input],
    out)


'''
Dataset Generators
'''
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 224,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 224)

# Datagen
def obtain_datagen(datagen, train_path, seed_number=7):
    return datagen.flow_from_directory(
                train_path,
                target_size=(img_height, img_width),
                batch_size=batch_size,
                seed=seed_number,
                class_mode='binary')

# Training data generators
train_generator_1 = obtain_datagen(train_datagen, train_data_dir_1)
train_generator_2 = obtain_datagen(train_datagen, train_data_dir_2)

# Validation data generators
validation_generator_1 = obtain_datagen(test_datagen, validation_data_dir_1)
validation_generator_2 = obtain_datagen(test_datagen, validation_data_dir_2)

# Yield for data generators
def generate_data_generator_for_two_images(genX1, genX2):
    while True:
            X1i = genX1.next()
            X2i = genX2 .next()
            yield [X1i[0], X2i[0] ], X1i[1]

# Yield for data generators
dataset_train_gen = generate_data_generator_for_two_images(train_generator_1, train_generator_2)
dataset_val_gen = generate_data_generator_for_two_images(validation_generator_1, validation_generator_2)


'''
Fine-tune the model
'''
# Freeze previous layers
for i, layer in enumerate(vgg_model_frontalization.layers):
    layer.trainable = False
for i, layer in enumerate(vgg_model_patch.layers):
    layer.trainable = False 

# Compile the model
custom_vgg_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])


'''
Callbacks
'''
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='weights/'+model_name+'.epoch-{epoch:02d}_val-accu-{val_acc:.2f}.hdf5', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
csv_logger = CSVLogger('logs/'+model_name+'.log', separator=',', append=False)


'''
Train the model
'''
print('*************************************\nFine-tuning the model \n*************************************')
custom_vgg_model.fit_generator(
    dataset_train_gen,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=dataset_val_gen,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples,
    callbacks=[checkpointer, csv_logger])
```

Comment: Do you properly close the session in your code?

Comment: @aseipel How do I close the session? In keras I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Try `K.clear_session()` - if that doesn't work, I'd suggest you show us your code

Comment: @aseipel I added the code to the description :)

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea other than trying `K.clear_session()`. You may also try out some of the suggestions from [this thread](http://forums.fast.ai/t/how-could-i-release-gpu-memory-of-keras/2023) and manually delete some of the variables and force the garbage collector to free memory.